# Page Not Redirecting to controller after generating a pdf file

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I am using Codeigniter as a PHP framework and DOM PDF to generate pdf files. I have the following codes in my Controller.

```
 // Some other codes

 include_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
 $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
 $base_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 $dompdf->load_html($html);
 $dompdf->render();
 $dompdf->stream("invoice_$studentid.pdf");

 redirect("my_Controller");
```

The problem is after generating the pdf file it is not redirecting to the Controller. Could you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$dompdf->stream` is sending the PDF to the browser. You can't *also* send a redirect header. You're trying to output two responses to one request, which is impossible.

This doesn't seem like it should be a problem. The browser will stay on whichever page the user was on when they clicked the link to download the PDF. If you really want them to be forced elsewhere (you probably don't, that's a very different user experience from how download links work everywhere else) you could do something with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I have a form. After a user submits the form, the information goes to database and then the code above generates a pdf file.  What I am trying to do is redirect the page to the same controller so that form's data do not stay in the input elements anymore after the pdf file is generated. But it’s not working. :(

Comment: Then you'll need to store the form's data server-side in the session or database, redirect the user, and then on the subsequent request either show a link to the PDF or trigger the downloading via JavaScript. Typically what you're talking about is done via four requests: GET form -> POST form -> redirect to "thank you" page -> trigger download